# Error al importar tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Instale tensorflow con

```
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
```

Se me descargo e instalo todo correctamente, pero al intentar importar me da el siguiente error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Eloy\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\Eloy\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.eager import context
  File "C:\Users\Eloy\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py", line 32, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import function_pb2
  File "C:\Users\Eloy\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\function_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import attr_value_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_attr__value__pb2
  File "C:\Users\Eloy\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\attr_value_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import tensor_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_tensor__pb2
  File "C:\Users\Eloy\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\tensor_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import resource_handle_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_resource__handle__pb2
  File "C:\Users\Eloy\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\resource_handle_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import tensor_shape_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_tensor__shape__pb2
  File "C:\Users\Eloy\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\tensor_shape_pb2.py", line 112, in <module>
    '__module__' : 'tensorflow.core.framework.tensor_shape_pb2'
TypeError: expected bytes, Descriptor found
```

Tengo python 3.7.6 y tensorflow 2.3 solo CPU

Comment: En este enlace esta la solucion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63877479/error-while-importing-tensorflow-typeerror-expected-bytes-descriptor-found/63885968#63885968